# Context Menu selection color and frame size Swift 5 iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview, ios13

I am trying to implement a simple report/block functionality to my app via the new iOS 13 context menu. It seems to work fine, however, I face problems with its appearance that I could not manage to solve at the moment.

1. When I long-press a `UICollectionViewCell`, it highlights black in a dark mode and that looks terrible since I have not all black background color. How can I change it to a clear color or the color I want?
2. I have a bubble that displays a user's message, and I would like to use the context menu for the bubbles. The problem is that when Context Menu previews my cell by default, it crops the bottom part of the bubble and it looks like just a part of the whole message. I tried to play with the height of the cell and some other parameters - nothing worked.

How can I fix the issues? Please, help.

****My code is:****

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil){ action in

            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)) as? ChatCell

        cell?.tintColor = .clear

        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear


           let messageText = cell?.textView.text

            let userNameZdes = cell?.nameView.text

            let report = UIAction(title: "Report", image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.bubble"), identifier: UIAction.Identifier(rawValue: "report")) {_ in
                print("report clicked..")

                if (cell?.textView.text.count)! > 2 {

                     print("the text of the message = \(messageText!) & the user is \(userNameZdes!)")

                } else {

                    print("the user has attached a bad pic")
                }

            }

            let block = UIAction(title: "Block user", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.xmark"), identifier: UIAction.Identifier(rawValue: "block"), attributes: .destructive) {_ in
                print("block clicked..")
            }
            return UIMenu(title: "Message Actions", image: nil, identifier: nil, children: [report, block])
        }
        return configuration
}
```

Comment: You have to provide a previewProvider in UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil), if you want to customize the default preview. On the other hand the selection color of the UICollectionViewCell is customizable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same struggle today and I found a solution that worked for me, so I hope it's relevant for you as well.

I found the solution in this post: https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide

If you scroll down to the section: `UITargetedPreview`, there's an example for a `UITableView` however you can apply the same solution for the UICollectionView :)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue. I fixed it by overriding UICollectionViewCell isHighlighted property. when didSet -> background color same as viewcontrollers background color and you're done.

so example asssuming your viewcontrollers/collectionview backgroundcolor = black, inside custom collectionviewcell class:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = .black
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code to improve your answer.